# Can we find Committer Role statistics in Beta?

Tags: discussion

When genealogy.se was in area51 it included a section which gave the number of committers and the percent of various roles. For example [Digital Preservation](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/39787/digital-preservation) has

> committer roles
>
> 58.6% Expert
>
> 14.7% Academic
>
> 11.7% Enthusiast
>
> 11.7% Beginner
>
> 3.3% Curious

Is that info (ie the percent in different roles) available now that we are in beta? It might help with the publicity question (ie see where we are succeeding and where we need work and should target more heavily).

Answer (score 2):

The question about our role was only asked when we committed at the Area 51 site to the Genealogy proposal. Therefore the roles are only available for the users who committed.

It is still available at Area 51 if you select [the "commitment" tab on our Area 51 page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/43502?phase=commitment). You'll see it says this (and I've calculated the numbers for you):

committer roles (263 committers)

11.8% Expert (31)

5.3% Academic (14)

48.7% Enthusiast (128)

27.4% Beginner (72)

6.8% Curious (18)

The question is not asked for new people who sign up at our beta site. So updated role information is not available.

But you can get an idea of how many people are more "expert" and how many are more "beginner" by checking how many questions and answers each person has.

Experts tend to ask few questions and answer lots of them.
Beginners tend to ask many questions and answer few of them.

This is just a general rule of thumb and there are exceptions, but it works well enough to get a general idea.

My current impression is that we don't have enough people asking questions. We've got a good base of established questions that serve as excellent examples of the type and quality of questions we are looking for. Now all we need is more people.

Hey everyone! It's time to get the word out!!